# how to write linux shell script to execute set of cli commands on remote machine begining from cli

Tags: shell

i am writing `shell script` on the server which has to executed set of `cli` commands on remote machine.
in my question remote machine is virtual machine in `vmware vsphere client`.i know the details of virtual machine i.e `ip address`, etc.... and also i know the all commands which needs to be ran.manually i am able to do that, but i can,t able to write the linux shell script for the same.
please note both are linux machines

list of commands

- cli
- configure
- set module element
- set Module Element  TenantInstance 1
- set Module Element  TenantInstance 1 attributes customParameter1 "some value"
- set Module Element  TenantInstance 1 attributes customParameter2  "some value"
- set Module Element  TenantInstance 1 attributes customParameter3   "somevalue"
- set Module Element  TenantInstance 1 ExternalVlan 4094 attributes label ISCSI-TRAFFIC

commit

confirm

etc ...

**can anybody please help me how to write the script Thanks in Advance!!**

Answer (score 1):

Put all the commands in a shell script on the remote vsphere machine, in say `/usr/local/bin/commands` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=something
configure
set module element ...
set Module Element TenantInstance 1
...
```

Then make the script executable, like this:

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/commands
```

Then run it locally on the vspehere machine using this command till it all works:

```
/usr/local/bin/commands
```

**Note**: If you encounter problems and need to debug the script, change the first line to the following in order to see the commands as they are expanded and run:

```
#!/bin/bash -xv
```

Simply remove the `-xv` when you are finished debugging.

Finally, go back to your server and run it remotely from there using `ssh` like this:

```
ssh vspehere_machine /usr/local/bin/commands
```